# Is It Possible To Deep Link To Whiteboard Functionality

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've been looking through the Teams deeplinkng documentation & haven't found much on this topic, does anyone know if it's possible to deeplink to the Teams white board functionality on mobile?

It looks like I could do this by linking to a whiteboard tab, but we don't want to have to setup a tab each time as this would get cumbersome.

It also looks like maybe I could deeplink to the whiteboard app itself with the following syntax https://teams.microsoft.com/l/app/your-app-id.

However the documentation seems to indicate this app deep linking functionality is more oriented around app installation than opening & using the app.

Answer (score 0):

Currently ,teams.microsoft.com/l/app/your-app-id links are not supported on Mobile.
You can add whiteboard App as tab,Use the following format for a deep link:

Link to a task item within the static (personal) tab:

> https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/fe4a8eba-2a31-4737-8e33-e5fae6fxxxxx/tasklist123?webUrl=https://tasklist.example.com/123/456&label=Task
> 456&context={"subEntityId": "task456"}

Link to a configurable tab itself:

> https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/fe4a8eba-2a31-4737-8e33-e5fae6fxxxxx/tasklist123?webUrl=https://tasklist.example.com/123&label=Task
> List 123&context={"channelId":
> "19:cbe3683f25094106b826c9cada3axxxxx@thread.skype"}

Reference Document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?tabs=teamsjs-v2#deep-link-to-your-tab